# Using Custom field inside of do_shortcode(); to use short-code explicitly within the PHP | WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have to use some WordPress short-codes for a project - but I want them in very specific places, and not in the main content. I need the client to just put them in specific Custom fields. Using ACF, I built a text field specifically for this.

```
// normal in-code use
<?php echo do_shortcode('[example_shortcode]'); ?>

// ACF field
<?php the_field('my_main_shortcode'); ?>

// ACF field in the do_shorcode
<?php echo do_shortcode( the_field('my_main_shortcode') ); ?>
```

This renders out `[example_shortcode]` on the page instead of what I would expect.

I'm guessing this is a standard PHP thing - and I don't know how to escape or concatenate it properly. EDIT - below using `get_fields` gets me closer...

THEN... with a more complex short-code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[tf_listview imagesize="medium1" exclude="calendar-link,list-view-title" dateformat="D n.j"]' ); ?>
```

It breaks somethings like the image by adding `""` - which could totally be the way the short-code was written / but basically - I haven't found a solution to using a short-code in a custom field like this.

Bottom line,

I'd like to write: `<?php shit_out('my_annoying_shortcode'); ?>`

Or something as close to that as possible. AND have it actually work.

Can anyone give me some more direction?

Comment: `concatenate it with the ' x ' quotes` what do you mean, it's the same way. The difference with `'` and `"` is the double quote does variable interpolation, ie. it will evaluate and replace variables with their values.

Comment: I think you are confusing  `the_field` displaying, with returning `get_field`. The first outputs the value, the second returns it.

Comment: (the x thing was a bad example)

Comment: It wasn't the bad example I meant, I meant this `"word ".$var." word"` is the same as `'word '.$var.' word'` only this `"word $var word"` is not the same as `'word $var word'`

Comment: Did you try this `<?php echo do_shortcode( var_export( the_field('my_main_shortcode'), true ) ); ?>`  It's cheating ( for string output ), I know.

Comment: RE: `var_export` - I'm trying to use as little higher lever PHP as possible since I use it so rarely. No room to learn a new set of quirks when there are so many in all the other areas of my work.

Comment: var export is not a quirk, largely it's used for debugging, but many overlook the second parameter.  With wordpress, tell me the function to get the header as a string?  there isn't one.  Doing it with output buffering is the only which is essential if you want to use wordpress for the front end and a custom backend, as wordpress only outputs the header.  With var_export you can use 1 line and don't have to worry about output buffering levels which was my point.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - Thank you. I didn't mean *it* was a quirk, just that it has some tricks and special knowledge associated with it - as you've explained. I'm more likely to build a front-end with Ember and use the WordPress as an admin panel - so, although that is super cool - I'm likely to use less PHP than more. Again, thank you. I'm likely to revisit this post and glean more at a later time.

Comment: Cool - anyway, the problem with get_header is it outputs content and destroys your ability to use sessions, and anything associated with headers after you call it.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down. I would also like to do this, and I don't see an actual answer here. Maybe you should change the title to be a bit more clear? "Using Custom field inside of do_shortcode(); to use short-code explicitly within the PHP | WordPress." Maybe this will help get some more eyes on this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `echo`, you need to use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), which `return`s the custom meta value:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('my_main_shortcode') ); ?>
```

Comment: well the OP could use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`, but that is a bit overkill in this example :).  Although it works great on `get_header()`. Really it's wordpress's fault for inconsistencies like this.  Personally this is better though `$out = var_export( $var, true )`

Comment: I don't understand what's inconsistent. WordPress and its plugins always `return` values with `get_` functions, and `echo` them with `the_` functions. Doing `echo echo $somevar;` will always lead to weird results, WordPress or not.

Comment: I don't really understand the differences - between `get_` and `the_` - field... but I'm also not sure I want to know. ~ but I'll give it a peruse and see if I can't get it to sink in. Is it an object literal thing?

Comment: In WordPress, functions such as `the_field()`, `the_title()`, and `the_content()` all echo/output/display values. Functions such as `get_field()`, `get_the_title()`, and `get_the_content()` all return values, for use in other parts of your PHP code. It's usually pretty consistent.

Comment: I hear you are supposed to `echo get_the_title()`  --- on another note... the example was simple... but now using `[tf_listview imagesize="medium1" exclude="calendar-link,list-view-title" dateformat="D n.j"]` things get whacky - probably because of the `"` etc. Any ideas on a better across the board solution?

Comment: Yes, you would `echo get_the_content()` and `echo get_field()` as well, because the functions return values...

Comment: what inconsistencies? this one what does get_header do? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header it doesn't say it but it doesn't get the header, it outputs the header, given that the_field, and the_* ~ outputs, and get_field returns, why does get_header output and not return? Again, tell me the function that returns the header as a string, I would love to know it. Would you echo get_header() or get_footer() ?